# Can I upgrade my 121 GB Flash Storage SSD?

Tags: macbook-pro, hardware, ssd, upgrade, storage

Is it possible to upgrade the 121 GB Flash Storage in my MacBook Pro 13" Retina? If so, can Apple do it for me or would I have to go to somewhere else to get it upgraded?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Retina MacBooks use a format of SSD that can be replaced, but Apple does not make it especially easy for simple replacement. Rather than the more familiar 2.5" HD format you might be familar with, the Retina use a newer blade style, somewhat similar to memory modules.

Your best bet it to look over the ifixit guides, to see what is involved:

https://www.ifixit.com/Guide/MacBook+Pro+13-Inch+Retina+Display+Early+2013+SSD+Replacement/15477

As far as I know, Apple offers repair and replace service for a Retina laptop, but I have not seen them offer 'upgrade' service. You could always complain about issues, and ask them to replace it with a newer, and larger size, but they would only do that if the part was orginally offered as an option on the Retina.

Good Luck!

Answer (score 2):

In the past, Apple doesn't upgrade any storage as a rule. This is HDD/SSD across the board. The only exceptions I've known are:

1. If you have several internal bays and you buy the part (Think Mac Pro with 4 SATA bays or Xserve / Xserve RAID)
2. You are paying for a service repair and they upgrade you for free to a larger drive. You don't ask for it, but Apple asks if you're OK with a better drive and no one refuses that offer.

You should ask them since it's free to ask and they might say yes one day.

That being said, there are many third party options to upgrade storage - but you need to hire someone else or DIY on that repair.

Everymac has a nice [overview of the options](http://www.everymac.com/systems/apple/macbook_pro/macbook-pro-retina-display-faq/macbook-pro-retina-display-13-how-to-upgrade-ssd-storage.html) and challenges as does [OWC](http://eshop.macsales.com/shop/SSD/OWC/Air-Retina/Apple-MacBook-Pro-Retina-2012-Drive-Internal-Flash).

Answer (score 0):

I do have a MacBook Pro 13" mid 2012 (no Retina), and I was able to upgrade both RAM (from 4GB to 16GB) and the drive (from the standard Hard Drive to Solid State Drive). I bought the items on Amazon and did it myself, it wasn't difficult at all (and there are tons of tutorials around the web).

You must check how old is your Mac: in the newest models you cannot upgrade anything (nor Apple can) because everything is settled on the MotherBoard (silly Apple rule).

Comment: I am pretty sure *no* Macbook Retinas have 2.5" drives. Most of them do, however, have the m.2 style (or something similar) SATA SSDs which are replaceable if you know where to look for the right part.

Comment: My MacBook is Mid 2014, so that would be too new, right?

Comment: @TonyStark you can apparently: https://www.ifixit.com/Guide/MacBook+Pro+13-Inch+Retina+Display+Mid+2014+SSD+Replacement/27849
Good luck!